# How can I take the numbers after the dot (.) in double?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to take the number after the dot (.)

for ex: 5.12
what I want is 0.12

this is my code:-

```
    double number= 5.12;
    int nInt= (int) number;
    double nDouble= number- nInt;

    if (nDouble== 0.12) {

        System.out.println(nDouble);

    } else {

        System.err.println(nDouble+ "\nThe answer should be (0.12)!!!");
    }
```

the code should give me 0.12
but it gives me 0.1200000000000001

How to fix this?

Comment: if you want to work with numbers which is important for you to get exact value for arithmetic calculation, you can use `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` in java

Comment: Use `BigDecimal`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

float nf = (float) nDouble;

try this!

Comment: thank you so much it worked